# Spring Scheduler to run at different timings on a single day

Tags: spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, spring-scheduled

I have a requirement where my scheduler has to run for every hour between 9 AM to 12 PM everday and then it runs once by 3PM and 5 PM respectively.

How can i make my CRON expression to work according to the requirement
So far i have tried with below cron expression

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 9-12 * * *")
```

But that runs for every hour from 9 AM - 12 PM
How can i modify it to make it run once by 3 PM and 5 PM also.

I have tried by combining two cron expressions like below but that dint work.

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 9-12 * * *, 0 0 3 * * *")
```

Can i give 2 cron expressions through 2 @Scheduled like below

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 9-12 * * *")
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 9-12 * * *")
public void myMethod() {}
```

Would that be a feasible solution?

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Use multiple annotations or something like `@Scheduled(cron = " 0 0 9-12,15,17 * * *)` the latter should work as well IIRC (else just use multiple annotations that will work).

Answer (score 0):

@Schedules annotation can be used to set multiple calendar-based timer expressions.

> This annotation will get rid of the redundancy of writing the same
> method multiple times.

In the following example, the first expression sets a timer to expire on the last day of every month. The second expression sets a timer to expire every Friday at 11:00 PM.

```
@Schedules ({
    @Schedule(dayOfMonth="Last"),
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek="Fri", hour="23")
})
public void doPeriodicCleanup() { ... }
```